# invalid fullname, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )

Tags: deployment, github

I m getting error invalid fullname, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c ) when deploying changes via Github (2 custom fields on , one on lead another on the Opportunity )to another sandbox.

Also verified the field names and api names too , it showing correct. Can anyone help me on this.

[image]

Comment: Please provide us the definitions of those fields.

Comment: @Damecek LAbel : MDR Footprint API name:MDR_Footprint__c . Names are same in both Lead and Opportunity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors of this nature occur when a specific feature is not enabled and you try to deploy the object/field that the specific feature exposes. Try enabling In-App Guidance in your org before deploying.

Comment: but i m not adding my fields any where in In-app Guidance and its not enabled in my Org  @Sfdxfox

Comment: @BRAHMAREDDY But it's in your metadata. If you're not using it, remove that object from your source code.

Comment: it worked for me thank you. After enalbeing the In app guidence it working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try matching the licenses in the target sandbox with Production by doing: Setup > Company Information > Match Production Licenses prior to your deployment. It worked for me.